# How to escape a backtick character in .backtickcsv file using java?

Tags: java, csv, escaping

the .backtickcsv file  contains

> Tim`Paul`Siren`UK`7.9``1987`

(seperated by backtick), when iam doing bulk insert from the .backtickcsv file it is treating Tim and paul as seperate where Tim`Paul is a single string . So i want to escape the backtick before writing into the file.

Comment: Why you must escape it?

Comment: Don't escape it but make sure that you can write unicode into your file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java. Your question is really "How to escape a backtick character in CSV?"

Comment: the .backtickcsv file  contains Tim``Paul``Siren`UK`7.9``1987`(seperated by backtick), when iam doing bulk insert from the .backtickcsv file it is treating Tim and paul as seperate. So i want to escape the backtick before writing into the file.

Comment: so replace it...

Comment: I have edited the question,Can someone tell me how to escape the backtick character?

Comment: Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) you can double quote fields in CSV data.Try that: `"Tim\`Paul"\`Siren\`UK\`7.9\`\`1987\``